# Allow Varnish cache, without per-cookie cache version only for a specific front-end cookie

Tags: jquery, caching, cookies, drupal, varnish

Bonjour à tous,

First post on Stack overflow ;)

I just want to understand process about Varnish.
I've not yet find an answer for my question on Internet.

I've a Drupal 7 website, in development, it uses a Varnish (v4), everything works fine. Now no cookie are generated by the Drupal site.

This website will allow each anonymous user to manage a "demand" (involving of many pages) and then to send the content of this demand to our back office. There is no users management or account management for anonymous users.
To improve the performance, I have installed Varnish but this is my real first experience with it.

I would like to implement the process of the "demand" using jQuery + a cookie to store all relevant information. Like this Apache (v2.4) will be not called at each request.

I think that if a cookie is generated, the caching process will be skipped by Varnish. I would like to use Varnish without per-cookie cache version only for a specific front-end cookie.

**So I would like to know if this is possible to say to Varnish:**

> **Hey Varnish even if this specific cookie is present (I mean managed,
>   cookie CRUD), do not take care of it and continue to serve the cached
>   page).**

If yes, could you explain me a bit about the logic.

Thank you in advance.

Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the application generates a cookie it sends a ***Set-Cookie*** header to the browser so it can store the new cookie. If Varnish finds this header it doesn't cache by default. This happens so the cookie is not set to other people's browsers erroneously. Summarizing, if you want to cache one page don't manipulate cookies in it.

**But** you can call a different page from that one you want to cache, using AJAX, that will be responsible for the cookies. In that way, your main page will be cached and every time you need to insert some cookies you will do it with that other page that does nothing but manipulate cookies.